# How to Move to a folder in the external SD card, by specifying the folder path in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-intent, android-sdcard

Please help, how to display the specified folder's contents, when click on a button by specifying the folder's full path.I tried like below, but My application crashes.

```
Button buttonFom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fom);
    buttonFom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getDir("/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/DOC1/HW 850Xp/");
        }
    });


private void getDir(String dirPath) {
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if (!dirPath.equals(root)) {

        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);

        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];
        path.add(file.getPath());
        if (file.isDirectory())
            item.add(file.getName() + "/");
        else
            item.add(file.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set user-permission to write access to SD card in Android Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Without it you can't access to SD card

Hope, it's help you.